# How to pull Quandl data into HighStock chart?

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts, frontend, quandl

I am trying to modify the data from the demo code on HighStock to pull data from Quandl instead of the default highstock api. Here is the [demo code](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/compare/) JSFiddle, and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bizkitgto/yvLaj0e1/) is my modified code in JSFiddle - but I don't know where I am going wrong.

In the original demo, the call was as follows:

```
$.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=' + name.toLowerCase() + '-c.json&callback=?',    function (data) {
```

I tried to modify the call from highcharts.com to Quandl as follows:

```
$.getJSON('https://www.quandl.com/api/v1/datasets/WIKI/' + name.toLowerCase() + '.json?auth_token=LnZgCF8fyVmHREMm9p3a',    function (data) {
```

Any thoughts or advice?

Comment: check [highchart data source](https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=msft-c.json&callback=) and [Quandl data source](https://www.quandl.com/api/v1/datasets/WIKI/msft.json?auth_token=LnZgCF8fyVmHREMm9p3a) there is huge difference , you have to process it according to highcharts

Comment: With addition to previous comment, you can find information about custom preprocessing data in Highcharts documentation:  https://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/custom-preprocessing